# How do we define a fact?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, truth

Got into a discussion today with my Semiotics professor regarding this question and I still had questions in my head on the way home.

He was stuck on the notion that facts have just become things that we have all agreed upon. Such a thing then extends to languages and the creation of words for certain objects.

Was wondering how you guys would answer such a question? 
Are there facts that can be defined as self-evident? 
What then happens if society suddenly looses sight of the notion of fact itself?

Also would be interested in reading other sources regarding this topic if you guys have any interesting ones to share.

Comment: See [Facts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/facts/): a *fact* is not only a "thing" (i.e. an individual) but sort of "complexe": a state of affair.

Comment: Maybe useful, in order to know how modern culture developed the concept of *fact* : Barbara Shapiro, [A Culture of Fact: England 1550-1720](https://books.google.it/books?id=3bMjoeWHQZQC&printsec=frontcover) (2000).

Comment: See also David Wootton, [The Invention of Science: A New History of the Scientific Revolution](https://books.google.it/books?id=4a7oBgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2015). Both sources can help us to understand that the notion of *fact* is a moder invention/discovery. So, maybe we can loose/forget it...

Comment: See the Tractatus https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractatus_Logico-Philosophicus